# For each value for $a$ and $b$, being real numbers, $a^2 + b^2 \ge ab$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each value for $a$ and $b$, being real numbers, $a^2 + b^2 \ge ab$

Should I solve this by replacing all possible real number formulas in these to be able to prove this? As an example for odd numbers, by replacing $2x + 1$, etc...?

Comment: We even have $a^2+b^2\geq2ab$. That's stronger, and easier to prove.

Comment: You have to prove this for any real numbers, so the strategy you are suggesting will not be useful as you cannot cover all types of numbers.

Comment: @Arthur Yes but $2ab \geq ab$ is not true in general

Comment: If it's about real numbers it doesn't make sense to speak of odd or even. But you could try to prove the stronger inequality $a^2+b^2 \ge 2 |ab|$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan True, but the LHS is always positive, so $2ab\geq ab$ holds in any case of interest.

Comment: @Arthur True. So we prove by cases then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to write it as $a^2+b^2-ab=\frac{2a^2+2b^2-2ab}{2}=\frac{a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2}{2}$. Now all three terms are $\geq 0$, so you get $a^2+b^2\geq ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

Either $(a \times b)$ is negative, or it isn't.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~(a \times b) ~\text{is negative}}$

Then, $a^2 + b^2 \geq 0 > (a \times b).$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~(a \times b) ~\text{is not negative}}$

Then $2(a \times b) \geq (a \times b).$ 
Further, since $(a - b)^2 \geq 0$ you have that 
$a^2 + b^2 \geq 2(a \times b) \geq (a \times b).$

Comment: Stylistically ,I find it odd using $\times$ for regular multiplication, even though it had its origins there!

Comment: @Alan I took literary license, thinking that $(a \times b)$ results in a more emphatic exposition than $(ab)$.

Comment: I usually use \cdot $\cdot$ when I want to emphasize the multiplication operator